# Servey Monkey API integration php Authorization

Tags: php

I am trying to get the collector list and keep getting a 401 response "The authorization token was not provided."

I can't understand what am I doing wrong:

```
$auth_data = [
    'Authorization : bearer ' . $accessToke,
    'contentType : application/json',
];

$cURLConnection = curl_init();

curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.surveymonkey.com/v3/surveys/119550392/collectors');
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $auth_data);
$list = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
curl_close($cURLConnection);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($list);
echo "</pre>";
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo in your headers declaration.
According to [HTTP specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2), there is no white space between header name and `:`

> Each header field consists of a case-insensitive field name followed
> by a colon (":"), optional leading whitespace, the field value, and
> optional trailing whitespace.

So

```
$auth_data = [
    'Authorization: bearer ' . $accessToke,
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Accept: application/json'
];
```

Note that I also fixed `contentType` to `Content-Type` and added `Accept` headers